# Help with query in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables:

1. Table **A**: `code` | `name`
2. Table **B**: `barcode` | `name`

Table **B** has full barcode and name, Table **A** has only code.

I need to run update query that fill name in Table A.

I tried something like:

```
update A set name = (select top 1 Name from B where B.Code = mid(A.Barcode,1,8))
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: At first glance, it seems it should work. what is the error?

Answer (score 2):

Name is a reserved word, you need to put it in square brackets: [name]

In general, fields (columns) should not be named with reserved words.

[`List of reserved words in Access 2002 and in later versions of Access`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335)